# How to block requests to an App Service originated from blacklisted IP addresses in AbuseIPDB

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-security

We constantly receive SQL injection attempts and other web app attacks from bots.

The IP addresses from this bots are blacklisted at AbuseIPDB.

I would like to know how could I automatically block all IP address blacklisted at AbuseIPDB from all my Azure App Services, does Azure have any feature to automate this process?

Also, is it possible to automatically block an IP address from sending requests if they made a specific amount of invalid requests in a given period of time?

Comment: have you looked at WAF? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/overview

Comment: @silent I did, but I find the Application Gateway to be quite expensive for its purpose (over $100 a month for a single WAF gateway)

Comment: depending on your traffic FrontDoor could be cheaper. Otherwise I guess you could try building something on your own with the IP filter in the app service. But not sure what the limit in number of rules there is.

Answer (score 0):

Using Only Web App you can use powershell / REST API to add IP Restrictions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdateconfiguration#ipsecurityrestriction

https://moimhossain.com/2018/07/31/azure-web-app-removing-ip-restrictions/

For a better management in terms of throttling you can use API Management in front of your App Service:

And apply the following policies:

[Restrict caller IPs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#RestrictCallerIPs)

[IP Address throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling#ip-address-throttling)

You can automate the changes through API Management REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/2019-01-01/apipolicy/createorupdate

PS: the API Management may be expensive, but it has a pay per consumption mode that can save you some money and deliver what you want.